# Lambda function in C# behaves weirdly

Tags: c#, lambda

What can be a reason why the code

```
Line ScoreLine;
ScoreLine = Charting.CreateLine(
        "Score", "", Symbol, new Pen(Color.Pink),
         LineStyle.Line, Charting.PriceChart, 2
);
```

leads to a different behavior than

```
Line ScoreLine;
Func<string, Color, int, Line> createLine
= (string label, Color color, int pad)
=> Charting.CreateLine(label, "", Symbol, new Pen(color),
                       LineStyle.Line, Charting.PriceChart, pad);
ScoreLine = createLine("Score", Color.Pink, 2);
```

It looks like a trivial refactoring but the second version behaves in a very strange manner. It seems like the parameters of the lambda function don't matter and are set to specific values a priori.

Comment: Which parameters? The ones you've hardcoded and closed over will remain baked into the `Func`, the others can be modified by passing different values to the `Func`. If you can come up with a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates otherwise, that would be very helpful in diagnosing the issue.

Comment: Can you describe what does happen a little better? Which values appear to be used? Where could they come from?

Comment: I cannot make a SSCCE easily because it is a GUI app and the results are only visible in the GUI.

What happens is that the second version does not plot a pink line, but plots a red line instead. Red was used in the past for the same line in the previous versions of the app.

Comment: In the previous version I also was specifying the lines to be thicker and when I run the second version the lines are thick.

Comment: Where are those previous values? Is it possible they're just defaults? I think there's too much going on that isn't in this question--the best answer might just be "no, there can't be a reason for the `Func` to behave this way and the mistake is elsewhere".

Comment: This may be a problem related to the lambda capturing certain variable values, but I'm not sure if what you posted above is **exactly** the code, or if you replaced some variables for constants (i.e. `Color.Pink` instead of a variable).

Comment: @31eee384, no, they are not defaults. They are used in previous versions of the program. I know it sounds very weird, but this is the behavior I observe

Comment: @RonBeyer, no I did not replace variables for constants. The code is like this and the only possible material difference is that Line is a member variable of a class.

Comment: A SSCCE doesn't require you to leave in GUI stuff. Can't you make an equivalent code path with only terminal output? Your question isn't about `Charting.CreateLine` so there's no reason it should stick around. What usually happens to me is that I go to make a SSCCE and I find out why some other part of my code's wrong while doing so. I highly recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

Test your code:

```
Func<string, Color, int, string> createLine 
    = ( label, color, pad ) 
    => ( "Label: " + label + " | pad: " + pad + " | Color: " + color.ToString( ) );

Console.WriteLine( createLine( "Test 1", Color.Red, 1 ) );
Console.WriteLine( createLine( "Test 2", Color.Green, 2 ) );
Console.WriteLine( createLine( "Test 3", Color.Blue, 3 ) );
```

and you should see this:

```
> Label: Test 1 | pad: 1 | Color: Color [Red] 
> Label: Test 2 | pad: 2 | Color: Color [Green] 
> Label: Test 3 | pad: 3 | Color: Color [Blue]
```

I think **Chris Knight** is right, your problem is that you assign your return value to a different class than `Line` and there will some other code which changes your color.

Comment: Thanks. I checked whether `ScoreLine.Color` was `Pink` throughout the `Line`'s lifetime. It was the case meaning that the line properties are overriden by the GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I see without knowing anything about what these charting things are is that your `Func<string, Color, int, Line>` says it returns a `Line`, but you are assigning the result of the method call to `ScoreLine` when using the lambda. In your non-lambda example you assign the result to `Line`. Could that be an issue? You are not saying what the types of `ScoreLine` and `Line` are, so I can't be sure.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. `ScoreLine` is of type `Line` and the assignment was meant to be to `ScoreLine` in both cases.